# How to split string by string in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to spit the string with a delimiter, which is a string:

```
$string = "5637144576, messag<>est<<>>5637145326, 1<<>>5637145328, 0"
$separator = "<<>>"
$string.Split($separator)
```

As the result of splitting I get:

```
5637144576, messag

est



5637145326, 1



5637145328, 0
```

Instead of

```
5637144576, messag<>est
5637145326, 1
5637145328, 0
```

When I try to use overloaded split which accepts string[]:

```
$string = "5637144576, messag<>est<<>>5637145326, 1<<>>5637145328, 0"
$separator = @("<<>>")
$string.Split($separator)
```

But I get next error:

```
Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "System.Object[]", for "Split" to type "System.Char[]": "Cannot convert value "<<>>" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one character long.""
```

Does someone knows how to split string by string?

Comment: Why should the separator `<<>>` split along `<>`?

Comment: Why should the separator <<>> split along <>?  - this is a problem which I faced and trying to solve

Comment: is it that you want to split along _any character of_ `<<>>`?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The `-split` operator uses the string to split, instead of a chararray like `Split()`:

```
$string = "5637144576, messag<>est<<>>5637145326, 1<<>>5637145328, 0"
$separator = "<<>>"
$string -split $separator

5637144576, messag<>est
5637145326, 1
5637145328, 0
```

If you want to use the `Split()` method with a string, you need the `$seperator` to be a stringarray with one element, and also specify a stringsplitoptions value. You can see this by checking its definition:

```
$string.Split

OverloadDefinitions                                                                                
-------------------                                                                                
string[] Split(Params char[] separator)                                                            
string[] Split(char[] separator, int count)                                                        
string[] Split(char[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options)                                
string[] Split(char[] separator, int count, System.StringSplitOptions options)                     

#This one
string[] Split(string[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options)      
string[] Split(string[] separator, int count, System.StringSplitOptions options)


$string = "5637144576, messag<>est<<>>5637145326, 1<<>>5637145328, 0"
$separator = [string[]]@("<<>>")
$string.Split($separator, [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

5637144576, messag<>est
5637145326, 1
5637145328, 0
```

EDIT: As @RomanKuzmin pointed out, `-split` splits using regex-patterns by default. So be aware to escape special characters (ex. `.` which in regex is "any character"). You could also force `simplematch` to disable regex-matching like:

```
$separator = "<<>>"
$string -split $separator, 0, "simplematch"
```

Read more about `-split` [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx).

Comment: `est` should be preserved. He seems to want to split by any character of `<<>>` (that is, along `<` and `>`)

Comment: sry, didn't see est in the sample of the output you wanted ^^  see updated answer

Comment: do you know, is possible to return only not empty string?

Comment: see last update. it explains the `Split()` methods behaviour too

Comment: "the -split operator uses the literal string to split" -- The -split operator uses a regular expression by default (without the SimpleMatch option). In this example it does not matter but generally speaking it does.

Comment: +1 I actually never read about split. Never tried to split with `.` etc. Just learned something new. You could actually use a scriptblock too, which is awesome! :)  But in this case with the pattern `<<>>` it uses the exact string. Will update the answer.

Comment: some alternatives for .split() `$string.split([string[]]'<<>>','none')` or `$string.split((,'<<>>'),0)`

Answer (score 2):

Instaed of using `Split` method, you can use `split` operator. So your code will be like this:

```
$string -split '<<>>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes PowerShell looks exactly like C# and at others, well you know...

It could also be used thus:

```
# A dummy text file
$text = @'
abc=3135066977,8701416400

def=8763026853,6433607660

xyz=3135066977,9878763344
'@ -split [Environment]::NewLine,[StringSplitOptions]"RemoveEmptyEntries"

"`nBefore `n------`n"

$text

"`nAfter `n-----`n"

# Do whatever with this
foreach ($line in $text)
{
    $line.Replace("3135066977","6660985845")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 2020-05-23: I've moved my code to GitHub, here, where I've made updates to cover a few edge cases: https://github.com/franklesniak/PowerShell_Resources/blob/master/Split-StringOnLiteralString.ps1

---

You can use the -split operator, but it expects RegEx. Furthermore, the -split operator is only available on Windows PowerShell v3+, so we need a different method if you want something that is universally compatible with all versions of PowerShell.

A [regex] object has a Split() method that can handle this as well, but again, it expects RegEx as the "splitter". To get around this, we can use a second [regex] object and call the Escape() method to convert our literal string "splitter" into escaped RegEx.

Wrapping all this up into an easy to use function that works back to PowerShell v1 and also works on PowerShell Core 6.x.

```
function Split-StringOnLiteralString
{
    trap
    {
        Write-Error "An error occurred using the Split-StringOnLiteralString function. This was most likely caused by the arguments supplied not being strings"
    }

    if ($args.Length -ne 2) `
    {
        Write-Error "Split-StringOnLiteralString was called without supplying two arguments. The first argument should be the string to be split, and the second should be the string or character on which to split the string."
    } `
    else `
    {
        if (($args[0]).GetType().Name -ne "String") `
        {
            Write-Warning "The first argument supplied to Split-StringOnLiteralString was not a string. It will be attempted to be converted to a string. To avoid this warning, cast arguments to a string before calling Split-StringOnLiteralString."
            $strToSplit = [string]$args[0]
        } `
        else `
        {
            $strToSplit = $args[0]
        }

        if ((($args[1]).GetType().Name -ne "String") -and (($args[1]).GetType().Name -ne "Char")) `
        {
            Write-Warning "The second argument supplied to Split-StringOnLiteralString was not a string. It will be attempted to be converted to a string. To avoid this warning, cast arguments to a string before calling Split-StringOnLiteralString."
            $strSplitter = [string]$args[1]
        } `
        elseif (($args[1]).GetType().Name -eq "Char") `
        {
            $strSplitter = [string]$args[1]
        } `
        else `
        {
            $strSplitter = $args[1]
        }

        $strSplitterInRegEx = [regex]::Escape($strSplitter)

        [regex]::Split($strToSplit, $strSplitterInRegEx)
    }
}
```

Now, using the earlier example:

```
PS C:\Users\username> Split-StringOnLiteralString "5637144576, messag<>est<<>>5637145326, 1<<>>5637145328, 0" "<<>>"
5637144576, messag<>est
5637145326, 1
5637145328, 0
```

Volla!

Answer (score 0):

The following should be what you need:

```
 $string -Split $separator
```

This produces:

```
5637144576, messag<>est
5637145326, 1
5637145328, 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This work well, when I declare a string. While getting content from a file it does not work as expected. You can try this out with the same content within a file.

Comment: Please add more result set or sample data with your response.
it will be make your answer more explanatory for others.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31897824)

Answer (score 0):

This actually works in powershell 7.

```
$string = "5637144576, messag<>est<<>>5637145326, 1<<>>5637145328, 0"
$separator = "<<>>"
$string.Split($separator)

5637144576, messag<>est
5637145326, 1
5637145328, 0
```

Powershell 7 actually has a new .split() overload that more closely matches a string as a first argument.  Surprisingly, the options 2nd argument can be left off, with a default 'None' value.

```
public string[] Split (string separator, 
  StringSplitOptions options = System.StringSplitOptions.None);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-7.0#system-string-split(system-string-system-stringsplitoptions)