# Powershell : split HTML

Tags: html, windows, powershell, split

I have a self generated HTML file (in a local directory) with all the body on one line:

```
<html><head><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>server - path</title></head><body><H1>server - path</H1><hr>

<pre><A HREF="/logs/folder/">[To Parent Directory]</A><br><br>         jeudi 5 janvier 2017    19:38       116483 <A HREF="/folder/file1.csv">file1.csv</A><br>         jeudi 5 janvier 2017    19:39       138397 <A HREF="/folder/file2.csv">file2.csv</A></A><br></pre><hr></body></html>
```

And I need to extract the name of the file and date.
I succeed to read the right line. But I'm blocked to split the line on `<br>`.

I try something like this:

```
$string = "first line<br>second line <br> third line<br> end<br>"
write-host $string
$separator = "<br>"
$option = [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries
$string.Split($separator, $option)
```

But I have that for result :

```
first line<br>second line <br> third line<br> end<br>
fi
st line
second line
thi
d line
end
```

I see the HTML Agility Pack, but in my case, I don't have any tag in my page.

Do you have any advice?
Thanks!

Comment: This post seems to answer your question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435240/how-to-split-string-by-string-in-powershell

Answer (score 3):

The [`String.Split()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) takes your string `<br>` and treats it as a `[char]` array, splitting on every single occurrence of either `<`, `b` ,`r` and `>`.

Use the regex-based `-split` operator instead:

```
PS C:\> $String -split $separator |Where-Object {$_}
first line
second line 
 third line
 end
```

The `Where-Object {$_}` pipeline element will filter out empty strings