# Info requested for the Powershell v7 '$String.split.OverloadDefinitions'

Tags: split

Powershell version 7.1,VSCode v5.1x, Net5, Windows 10

Objective: To learn the string.split.overloaddefinitions method and parameters.
Using VSCode it is an option from the split to select the overloaddefinitions as...$Hash=$String.split.OverloadDefinitions(?)
MS Docs (link included) state that it has 3 options (0,1,2)but the detail is very sparse.
Is it 1 numeric or "1" string or literal "RemoveEmptyEntries"? I have tried many variants and none work.
So I am seeking some guidance as to what I am missing or misunderstanding.
The runtime error when using this overload is always "does not contain a method named 'OverloadDefinitions'." which seems to be an erroneous message.
Using Set-Transcript captures the result but this is not useful because the bottom line is still the same error.
The C# examples have been tried with worse results. So now what?

The code snippet for testing is...
#Start-Transcript  "C:\Users\AlPerkins\Desktop\Transcript.txt"    #transcript available but not included

## https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=net-5.0

```
$String="Harry & Joanne  Joint open statement as of June 4 2021"
$Hash=$String.Split()                                               # OK but with empty entries from spaces. Empties need to be removed.
$Hash=$String.split.OverloadDefinitions("1")     # OK in VSCode editor but runtime errors-> 'does not contain a method named 'OverloadDefinitions'. '            
$Hash=$String.split.OverloadDefinitions("2")                        # Ditto
$Hash=$String.split.OverloadDefinitions(1)                          # Ditto
$Hash=$String.split.OverloadDefinitions(2)                          # Ditto 
$Hash=$String.split.OverloadDefinitions("RemoveEmptyEntries")       # Ditto
$Hash=$String.split.OverloadDefinitions("TrimEntries")              # Ditto
```

## [How to split string by string in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435240/how-to-split-string-by-string-in-powershell) and other

## ideas from stackoverflow but my attempts fail -  Nothing from here will even compile. The examples here are C# code and I am not a C# guy.

## so the above are my best options if I can get the method options to work.

```
<# $Hash=$String.Split(" ",System.­StringSplitOptions "RemoveEmptyEntries" )        #Note the char '-' in these lines ere not type by me but are char('AD')
$Hash=$String.Split(' ',[System.­StringSplitOptions]::­"TrimEntries")
$Hash=$String.split(' ',[System.­StringSplitOptions]::"RemoveEmptyEntries")
$Hash=$String.Split(' ',[System.­StringSplitOptions]::­"RemoveEmptyEntries, [System.­StringSplitOptions]::­"TrimEntries")
#>
```

Anyone that has been successful with this approach please kick start me on the right track because I have fallen of my bike here.

Many Thanks

Comment: Late to the party here but I finally resolved this for my purpose with the following. # $TextObj=$text.Split("`n", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries::TrimEntries ). The sequence seems important as swapping removeemptyentries and trimentries returned an error. It also seems that an entry that contains spaces (char(32) ) is NOT empty.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so far after a VSCode update to 1.57
$Split=$FName.Split(" ", [System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)
This now works but it still will not work with...
$Split=$Fname.Split.OverLoadDefinitions(  )
Seems like this a PS problem as every effort returns an error 'Method OverloadDefinition unknown'.

Answer (score 0):

Since original post I have no responses except a mysterious prompt to update VSCode v1.56 to VSCode v1.57. As I earlier stated this improved things immensely albiet that the method $Hash=$String.split.OverloadDefinitions() still errored.
Since then I have reviewed and checked the string.split further and again mysteriously the method ...split.OverloadDefinitions is no longer an option in IntelliSense.
So this was a VSCode bug issue.
Issue Closed.