# Removing strings from before and after of two specific strings in PowerShell ExpandProperty of CommandLine

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a part of PowerShell ExpandProperty return by removing everything (String/Characters) before the word `--device` and after the  `mapserver`. So the output looks like `--device-scale-factor-mapserver`

```
$str = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = '14840'" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty CommandLine
$str.CommandLine
$str.Split('--device')[-1]
$str
```

but the `$str.Split('--device')[-1]` is not doing the job

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=renderer --disable-nacl --origin-trial-disabled-features=WebGPU --lang=en-US --device-scale-factor-mapserver=1 --num-raster-threads=2 --en
able-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=69 --time-ticks-at-unix-epoch=-170003960238778825810279 --launch-time-ticks=11174444444170           
   88642 --mojo-platform-channel-handle=7412 --field-trial-hand
le=1960,i,183ds1827975sd7468sss406768,131sdsd35554053270777202,262144 /prefetch:1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the output from `$str`? In this case `$str` isn't mutated as `$str.split("--device")[-1]` returns a new string and  you haven't assigned the new string value to the original variable name. Also I tested on Windows PowerShell, somehow the string.split method fails to work and gives nonsensical results, but PowerShell 7 works.

Comment: This script will extract the part of the string starting from --device and ending with mapserver? I'm right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$process = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessId = '14840'"
$matches = [regex]::matches($process.CommandLine ,'--(device(?:.*?)mapserver)')
$matches.foreach({$_.value})
```

Answer (score 0):

`string[] Split(Params char[] separator)` splits by each character, not by the whole word.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-8.0#system-string-split(system-char()) -Split will work better:

```
 ('--lang=en-US --device-scale-factor-mapserver=1 --num-raster-threads=2' -split '--device')[-1]

-scale-factor-mapserver=1 --num-raster-threads=2
```

String.Split() works as expected in powershell 7.  Or have the separator be a string array and add the string split option to match the right function overload:

```
'--lang=en-US --device-scale-factor-mapserver=1'.split([string[]]'--device','None')

--lang=en-US
-scale-factor-mapserver=1
```

Overloads:

```
'--lang=en-US --device-scale-factor-mapserver=1'.split

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
string[] Split(Params char[] separator)
string[] Split(char[] separator, int count)
string[] Split(char[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options)
string[] Split(char[] separator, int count, System.StringSplitOptions options)
string[] Split(string[] separator, System.StringSplitOptions options)
string[] Split(string[] separator, int count, System.StringSplitOptions options)
```

Probably a duplicate of [How to split string by string in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16435240/how-to-split-string-by-string-in-powershell)